# Open another version of interpreter after Py_Finalize

Tags: python, cpython

Can I close interpreter of python 2.7 with Py_Finalize and open interpreter with Python3.9 with Py_Initialize after that?

I need at first run some code with Python2.7, but then with Python3.5

I try do Py_Finalize, then set python3.9 interpreter version and do Py_Initialize again, but sys.version == python2.7 still

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.